# C++ Use non-static variable inside staic function to return class instance

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a application which has the possibility of having multiple windows open. There are `id`'s associated with these windows.

I have a `map<uint, Window*>` data structure which keeps track of the mappings between id's and windows.

I am attempting to return an instance of a class where I know the id:

```
Window * Window::getWindow(uint id) {

    map<uint, Window*>::iterator it = m_windows.find(id);
    if (it != m_windows.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    } 
}
```

It is being called from another class, via:

```
Window::getWindow(id)
```

I found that the function needed to be declared `static` in order to be able to call this function without having the object itself, so the function is declared as:

```
static Window * getWindow(uint id);
```

The issue, is that `m_windows` is **not** static. It is declared:

```
std::map<uint, Window*> m_windows;
```

Therefore, I can't use it (knowingly) inside this function.

I'm trying to figure out how I would be able to either

- use `m_windows` from inside this static function
- make this function non-static and return the class instance a different way

`m_windows` cannot be static as well, as new windows need to be able to be added to this map as well as removed from it.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe `m_windows` should be static also?

Comment: This won't work as it needs to be dynamic and flexible to accept new windows :(

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding `static`. Even if static you can still add new windows to the map.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

1. Keep `Window::getWindow` as a `static` member function.
2. Move the map, `m_windows`, to the implementation file as an implementation detail. There is no need to keep it as a member variable of the class, `static` or otherwise.

---

In the .cpp file, use:

```
// Function to return a reference to the map of windows, which
// is stored in a static variable in the function.
static std::map<uint, Window*>& getWindowsMap()
{
   static std::map<uint, Window*> windows;
   return windows;
}
```

When adding an item to the map, use:

```
getWindowsMap()[id] = window;
```

When getting back an item from the map, use:

```
Window* window = getWindowsMap()[id];
```

Comment: Why not make it a private static member of the class? Why do you need a method to return it?

Comment: @Barmar "Why not...private static member" Better encapsulation; because you'll force clients to recompile if you change implementation (e.g., use unsorted_map instead of map), and private membership still leaks implementation details (in particular, you force all users to include <map>, which has nothing to do with the interface).

Comment: Isn't the whole point of private members that they're invisible to users, so they don't need to recompile if it changes?

Comment: @Barmar No; the point of private members is that they are inaccessible to users, not invisible.  Ping me in chat if you like and I can explain why (too long for a comment, not appropriate for an answer, and this is not the right place for extended discussions).

Comment: @Barmar, changing private data still requires a recompile.

Comment: Hi, a few questions.  For point `2.`, this should be moved to the class that is **not** the `Windows` class. It should be moved to wherever I am calling `Window::getWindow(id)` correct?

You also say 'in the .cpp file, use:'  - Is this also a reference to that other class? I ask because since there's not a class signature in the function name, I got a little confused. Doesn't there need to be a class reference in the name when saying `static std::map<uint, Window*>& getWindowsMap()`?

Thanks

Comment: No. No. My thought was to keep `static std::map<uint, Window*>& getWindowsMap()` in the .cpp file that implements `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a static is, in my opinion, the right way to go.  In order to use a std::map in the static method, you need to make the std::map static too.

I'd approach this by creating a simple class or struct with a std::map data member and methods for adding/removing windows from the map, as well as a method for returning the window based on id.

Add/remove from the map when new windows are created/destroyed, and your method above would work about as is.

FYI - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglobalstatic.html may help if you decide to create such a class.